# Whoosh Concurrency Search

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, concurrency, whoosh

I have an index (size = 3.5 GB) of 5 million small documents indexed using Whoosh.

As my documents have only **name** and **content**, therefore my `Schema` is very simple and has only two fields: `id` and `content`.

```
schema = Schema(name = ID(stored=True),
                content = TEXT(stored=True),
                )
```

To test performance, I'm using a set of 70,000 queries, but Whoosh is taking about 20 seconds to execute each one.

```
index = open_dir("../data/search/bm25_index/")
query_parser = QueryParser("content", schema=index.schema)
q = query_parser.parse("some query")
with index.searcher(weighting=scoring.TF_IDF()) as searcher:
    results = searcher.search(q)
```

Since the index is stateless, how could I perform a multi-thread search?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the multi-threading of python. Look at `pool` or `process`.